# jquery noConflict jquery.mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using two versions of jQuery and i want to start using jQuery mobile. See below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">var jQuery_2_1_0 = $.noConflict(true);</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
```

Now the problem is, that jquery.mobile recognises the 1.4.2 version of jquery.

**How do i tell jquery.mobile to use the 2.1.0 version?**

!! *The noConflict cannot be used for 1.4.2 version, because of legacy code and one jquery version is not an option for now.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this question is old, but it's still open.

Here is a snippet of my solution:

```
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js'></script>

<script>
  $(function () {
    // jQuery Mobile has loaded with the newer version of jQuery, so
    // now we set $ back to the original version of jQuery & set new version to jq2
    var jq2 = jQuery.noConflict();
  });
</script>
```

See the rest on CodePen: http://codepen.io/rothkj1022/pen/gapNeP